# Rewriting link with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to rewrite links with .htaccess file. Basic stuff, but for some reason it does not work. I need the name of the file, before .php to be the last word in URL. What am I missing here?

```
RewriteRule ^/product/(.*)$ /incl/static/products/$1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Your regex is grabbing everything up to the end of the url, so `/product/this/that/something.php?blah=blah` will make $1 equal to `this/that/something.php?blah=blah`.

Comment: Wait, did I do it backwards? How do I put $1 after /product/ ?

Comment: You'd need something like `RewriteRule ^/product/(.*).php(.*)$`, to capture both the script name ($1) AND the query string ($2) separately. Otherwise, you'll just end up with `/product/test.php` turning into `/incl/static/products/test.php.php`

Comment: I don't need file extension. /incl/static/products/item.php should become /product/item

Comment: What's the URL that you're using to test this?

Comment: @santa: then yes, you've got your rule backwards. it's `RewriteRule original rewrittenversion [options]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as  `Marc` said you need something to distinguish the script file name and other parts:

```
RewriteRule ^products/script/(.*)/(.*)$    $1.php?$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

But if after first (.*) is query string , so use it:

```
RewriteRule ^products/script/(.*)$    $1.php?%{QUERY_STRING}
```